# Automating HTA - Html Application Testing

Tags: automated-tests, hta

Are there any tools available to perform automated testing of HTA - Html Applications that runs in IE? My application is a hta file that has the required css and minimal images that are required during startup, other images during application flow are downloaded from the web server. How do I automate the testing of this hta application?

Answer (score 1):

If HTA is opened in IE, then I guess Selenium can handle that http://seleniumhq.org/